# Concatenate JsonRepresentation

Tags: json, concatenation, restlet

How can I concatenate multiple JsonRepresentation Object into one, without building my own string parser?

Say I have two JsonRepresentation objects

```
obj1 = {"name":"obj1"};
obj2 = {"name":"obj2"};
```

I would like to get the result concatenation as:

```
 {
    {"name":"obj1"},
    {"name":"obj2"}
 }
```

Reading the JsonRepresentation, there is no easy way to do this except by doing some string manipulation. Am I right?

Thanks

Comment: @portoalet, if the JsonRepresentation you mention is part of the RestLet library, please tag the question as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to [this JsonRepresentation class](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/1.0/ext/org/restlet/ext/json/JsonRepresentation.html), and you want to merge the 2 objects into an array, then you should be able to do it as follows:

```
JSONObject jsonObj1 = obj1.toJsonObject();
JSONObject jsonObj2 = obj2.toJsonObject();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray().append(jsonObj1).append(jsonObj2);
JsonRepresentation jsonConcat = new JsonRepresentation(jsonArray);
```

Note: I haven't actually used the library, but if it behaves per the API, this should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: thanks! I thought I can do everything without using JSONArray